# Skipping a for-Loop with an if-Statement

Tags: python, numpy

I have managed to write the following code for the following problem:

> Projectile's horizontal and vertical displacement are given by:
>
> `x = v_0 \, t \cos(\theta)`
>
> `y = v_0 \, t \sin(\theta) - \frac{1}{2}gt^2`
>
> Consider the time interval to be `t \in [0, 60] seconds`. Write a Python code to plot horizontal and vertical displacements (meaning `y`
> as a function of `x`) with the initial velocity `40 m/sec` for four
> angles (30, 45, 60, and 75 degrees) on the same graph. Then save
> your data in a text file.

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v = 40
g = 9.8

def x(theta):
    return ((v*t)*np.cos(theta*np.pi/180))

def y(theta):
    return ((v*t)*np.sin(theta*np.pi/180))-((0.5*g)*(t**2))

t = np.linspace(0, 60,600)

table = t
for theta in range(30, 90, 15):
    X = x(theta)
    Y = y(theta)
    if np.all(Y < 0):
        break
        
    plt.plot(X, Y, label=theta)
    
    table=np.column_stack((table,X, Y))                             
np.savetxt("projectile_1.txt", table, fmt='%.3e', delimiter="  ")

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.title("Range as a Function of Angle")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I do know that the problem is from the negative values of `Y` (the vertical displacement below the floor). Why my if statement does not break the loop and consequently excluding those negative values from both the plot as well as from the saving file? How to skip saving and plotting the negative values?

Comment: It is saving the file because the function to save the file is outside the loop function, you can fix this by setting a variable to true before the break function, and when saving check if the variable you set is true, if it is then it will save else dont save the file, also try using pass instead of break as it will pass the iteration where the value is negative and not break the entire loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set all the negative values to None. Note that if you want to remove all the 'nan' from the text output, you can simply replace them in line with fileinput. Note that this does change the shape of the data if you plan on using it later on.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import fileinput

v = 40
g = 9.8

def x(theta):
    return ((v*t)*np.cos(theta*np.pi/180))

def y(theta):
    return ((v*t)*np.sin(theta*np.pi/180))-((0.5*g)*(t**2))

t = np.linspace(0, 60,600)

table = t
for theta in range(30, 90, 15):
    X = x(theta)
    Y = y(theta)
    
    X[X < 0] = None
    Y[Y < 0] = None
        
    plt.plot(X, Y, label=theta)
    
table=np.column_stack((table,X, Y))                             
np.savetxt("projectile_1.txt", table, fmt='%.3e', delimiter="  ")

with fileinput.FileInput("projectile_1.txt", inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace('nan', ''), end='')


plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.title("Range as a Function of Angle")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I edited my response, it now adjust both Y and X to all the positive values... If you were to expand this, you should do checks (make sure both X and Y are positive and correct size, in this case Y determines the correct size). I removed the linear spacing of (0,60,600)... You can add it back in, but keep in mind that the Size of the list will not be 600 each time as you're removing all the negative values. This table and t will have to be redefined in the for loop based on the size of Y.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how to include the **time** coordinates as well to the saving file. The problem is that now (after excluding the negative ones) the sizes of `X` and `Y` are not equal to the size of the `t` array to be stacked together. My main goal apart from the plot is to save the data into a file, which should be composed of 9 columns (1 `t` + 4 `X` + 4 `Y`).

Comment: There's two things you can do, adjust the line spacing each loop iteration ex: t = np.linespace(0, 60, Len(Y)) + padding or keep the data the same size and set all the negatives to 0 ex: Y[Y<0] = 0 and X[X<0]=0

Comment: Dear @Kestutis Saltonas setting the negative values to zero seems a good trick; however, its plot looks strange. All the trajectories form a closed path at the base of the x-axis. As for the first suggestion I, actually, do not understand it, and do not know how to implement it.

Comment: @Sha I see what you mean, in that case set the values to "None" ... It will show up as NAN in the text out put and the graph should look like you want it.

Comment: @Sha I've added a section of code that using FileInput to remove the 'nan' from the output file. Note that this does change the shape of your data in case you're using it for more processing.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out to compute the total time for the projectile to hit the ground; thus, avoiding the negative values altogether:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v = 40   #initial velocity
g = 9.8  #acceleration due to Earth's gravity

#Defining the Horizontal and Vertical Displacements
def x(theta):
    return ((v*t)*np.cos(theta*np.pi/180))

def y(theta):
    return ((v*t)*np.sin(theta*np.pi/180))-((0.5*g)*(t**2))

columns = []  #an empty List to be used for saving the Data 

for theta in range(30, 90, 15):
    t_total = 2 * v * np.sin(theta*np.pi/180)/g  #Time to hit the ground
    t = np.linspace(0, t_total,600)
    
    X = x(theta)
    Y = y(theta)
    
    plt.plot(X, Y, label=theta)
    
    columns += [t,X,Y]
    
    T = np.column_stack(columns)
    
np.savetxt("Data.txt", T, fmt='%.3e', delimiter="  ")


    
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.title("Range as a Function of Angle")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[The Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tsk0.png)